# How to prepare the nodes folder structure for the network-bootstrapper?

Tags: corda

I am trying to create a bootstrap test network on aws, and I am using this -

```
java -jar corda-tools-network-bootstrapper-4.5.jar --dir ./
```

I get -

> Bootstrapping local test network in /home/ubuntu No nodes found

The jar seems to be correct. The docs state - https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/network-bootstrapper.html -

```
java -jar network-bootstrapper-4.5.jar --dir <nodes-root-dir>
```

I cannot find network-bootstrapper-4.5.jar but only the corda-tools-network-bootstrapper-4.5.jar. The error seems to be something related to the node.conf file.

Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: I improved the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the steps that are mentioned [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/network-bootstrapper.html#bootstrapping-a-test-network), you will see that it says:

> Create a directory containing a node config file...for each node

The keywords are `node config file`; so you must do the following:

1. Build your nodes: From the root folder of your project run `./gradlew deployNodes`; this will create a folder for every node that you defined inside the `deployNodes` Gradle task of your root `build.gradle` file.
2. The folders will be inside `path-to-project-folder/build/nodes`. If you inspect the folders, you'll see that each node has a `node.conf` file which the documentation of the bootstrapper is talking about.
3. Run the bootstrapper command where the `<nodes-root-dir>` is `path-to-project-folder/build/nodes` since it contains all of your nodes.